# share Stimulusjs controller with rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm developing a rails engine for Rails6. I would like to include Stimulus controller in that rails engine. main app use Webpacker. and would like to move grid_controller.js to my rails engines as include this automatically in main app.

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import { Application } from "stimulus"
import { definitionsFromContext } from "stimulus/webpack-helpers"
```

app/javascript/controllers/grid_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
sort(event) {
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  var attr = event.target.dataset.attr
  var dir = urlParams.get("dir") || 'asc'
  var currentAttr = urlParams.get("sort")
  var currentURL = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname
  if (attr == currentAttr){
    dir = ((dir == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc')
  }
  var gotoURL = currentURL+'?'+'sort='+attr+'&'+'dir='+dir
  window.location.href = gotoURL
```

}
}

[structure in my engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl7bY.png)

Comment: HI, you need to more specific with your question. Please describe what steps you have taken and what the problem is you´re facing.

Comment: @KFoobar I have include detail in what I'm trying to do. Thank you